# curl request being sent twice when image included below PHP

Tags: php, html, api, curl

I made a bit of a web thingy with html and PHP. Its purpose is to take query parameters (from a NFC card being scanned) and rearrange them into a    API request for monday.com.

When the NFC card is scanned it directs the device(android scanner) to a webpage on a local machine which asks for conformation before sending the request.

I'm trying to include a company logo on the pages that pop up after confirming I want the request sent or canceled. If cancel is selected it shows the logo and no request is sent. But the page that is displayed when "YES" is selected wont show the image, even though the file has the same directory relation to the image as the "CANCEL" page and uses the exact same  element.

At first that was all I noticed untill I looked at monday.com (where im sending the API request to) and noticed that when i tried to include the image on the YES page, the request is sent twice,although the second time without parameters.

In the code below the curl request is sent once if the line:

```
<img style="height: 30vh" id="hdlogo" src="images/1947.png" alt="Company logo" >
```

is commented out, but twice if its included. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

**sent.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body{
            background-color: #282824;
            text-align: center;
        }
        h1 {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            height: 30vh; /* set height to fill viewport */
            margin: 0; /* remove default margin */
            color: white;
            font-size: 4vh;
        }
        a {
            border-right: 2px solid #fe972e ;
            color: #dfddd0;
            display: block;
            font-size: 5vh;
        }
    </style> 
</head>
<body>

<?php

echo $_GET['v'];
    $vendor = $_GET['v'];
    // echo $vendor;

    echo $_GET['p'];
    $partNumber = $_GET['p'];
    // echo $partNumber;

    echo $_GET['d'];
    $description = $_GET['d'];
    // echo $description;

    $myColumnValues = array(
        'text' => $vendor,
        'text7' => $partNumber,
        'text5' => $description
    );

    $payload = json_encode(array(

        'query' => 'mutation ($myColumnValues: JSON!) { create_item ( 
board_id: MY_BOARD_ID, group_id: "topics", item_name: "My Item", 
column_values: $myColumnValues ) { id } }',

        'variables' => array(
            'myColumnValues' => json_encode($myColumnValues)
        )
    ));

    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(

        CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.monday.com/v2',
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $payload,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            'Authorization: MY_AUTH_HERE',
            'Content-Type: application/json',
        ),
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    echo $response;
?>

<img style="height: 30vh" id="hdlogo" src="images/1947.png" alt="Company logo" >
        
<h1 style="color:#1f5e16"> REQUEST SENT </h1>

</body>
```

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body{
            background-color: #282824;
            text-align: center;
        }
        h1 {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            height: 30vh; /* set height to fill viewport */
            margin: 0; /* remove default margin */
            color: white;
            font-size: 4vh;
        }
        a {
            display: block;
            font-size: 5vh;
        }
    </style> 
</head>

<body>

    <img style="height: 30vh" id="hdlogo" src="images/1947.png" alt="Company logo" >

    <?php

        // get the query parameters from the GET request initiated by a NFC card
        // the query parameters "names" are kept short to preserve as many charicter as possible for data(NFC card is limeted)
        $vendor = $_GET['v'];
        $partNumber = $_GET['p']; 
        $description = $_GET['d'];
        

        echo "<h1> Do you want to place an order request for <br> $description ? </h1>";

        echo "<a style=\"color:#1f5e16\" href=\"sent.php/?v=$vendor&p=$partNumber&d=$description\"> YES </a>";
        echo "<br><br><br><br><br>";
        echo "<a style=\"color:#8f0909\" href=\"cancel.html\"> CANCEL </a>";

    ?>
    
</body>
```

**cancel.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body{
            background-color: #282824;
            text-align: center;
        }
        h1 {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            height: 30vh; /* set height to fill viewport */
            margin: 0; /* remove default margin */
            color: white;
            font-size: 4vh;
        }
        a {
            display: block;
            font-size: 5vh;
        }
    </style> 
</head>

<body>
    <img style="height: 30vh" id="hdlogo" src="images/1947.png" alt="company logo" >

    <h1 style="color:#8f0909"> REQUEST CANCELED </h1>

</body>
```

Comment: It makes no sense that adding HTML code for an image, would make parts of your PHP code execute multiple times. When you check the requests made by the browser in the network panel - do you see anything getting requested more than once, or a redirect maybe, that could trigger the execution of the code a second time?

Comment: `href=\"sent.php/?v=$vendor&p=` - what is that slash after the file name doing there? This could well be the reason why a second request is made, depending on how your server responds to the request to this URL.

Comment: Yup that did it, nice catch! want to make that an answer so I can mark it correct?

Comment: The community rather prefers questions like this to be closed as "caused by a typo". It is unlikely that an answer would be of much benefit to future users, it is too specific of a situation for that.